# Custom data entry form (.ui) crashes qgis

Tags: qgis, ubuntu, qt4

I'm using Linux Mint 17.2, qgis 2.8.1 and have also tried this on 2.10:

- Made a simple form using qt4 designer
- The field names match those in the attribute table
- used the properties page of qgis to select the "provide ui" option
- click Apply and okay
- using the attribute identify tool clicked on the layer

instantly crashes qgis.

BTW, this is my first question, but have learned a lot from those posted by others.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This [bug has been reported](http://hub.qgis.org/issues/8760) specifically for Ubuntu and Mint is also affected as one of its derivatives.

The bug report also mentions a [workaround](http://hub.qgis.org/issues/8760#note-2).

Open the .ui file with a text editor and search for properties with the name `size` and `geometry` and delete these from the xml file.

## Example

### Before

```
<widget class="QDialog" name="Dialog">
 <property name="geometry">
  <rect>
   <x>0</x>
   <y>0</y>
   <width>687</width>
   <height>665</height>
  </rect>
 </property>
 <property name="sizePolicy">
  <sizepolicy hsizetype="MinimumExpanding" vsizetype="MinimumExpanding">
   <horstretch>0</horstretch>
   <verstretch>0</verstretch>
  </sizepolicy>
 </property>
 ...
```

### After

```
<widget class="QDialog" name="Dialog">
 <property name="sizePolicy">
  <sizepolicy hsizetype="MinimumExpanding" vsizetype="MinimumExpanding">
   <horstretch>0</horstretch>
   <verstretch>0</verstretch>
  </sizepolicy>
 </property>
 ...
```

Comment: Hi Frank, if it solves your question you can accept the answer as correct by clicking the tick on the left side.